# Create a Virtual MIDI device (Windows, c++)

Tags: c++, windows, audio, driver, midi

I am trying to create a virtual MIDI device, so my app can generate midi events and another third party app can pick up these events and act based on them.

Most answers (quite old ones) I’ve searched on SO suggest using third party kernel drivers which are neither opensource nor free (like http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/virtualmidi/virtualmidi-sdk.html) or just asking the user to install a third party virtual midi cable driver.

Is there currently any advancements on modern builds of Win10 (UWP) that allow creating virtual midi devices without building a kernel driver, or we still have to go the hard way?

Is My understanding correct that a virtual midi device is impossible to create as a user mode multimedia driver?

Comment: Currently not production-ready, but Windows will be introducing a [new MIDI API](https://github.com/microsoft/MIDI) at some point in the future, which should make this far simpler in the future from what I can spot in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there have been no advancements in this area in Windows. Developers still have to do this the hard way.

Considering how long Microsoft has left MIDI device enumeration broken (it has been years since they acknowledged the reports of the issue) there is little hope of Microsoft providing a built-in way of creating virtual MIDI devices any time soon, if ever.